# lisp macro multiplication that stops evaluating when sees a 0

Tags: macros, lisp

I'm pretty new to LISP and I have no idea how to make my infinite-argument functions stop evaluating the rest of the arguments when one of the factors is a 0. I've tried this

```
(defmacro smart_multiplication (&rest l)
  (unless(member 0 l) `(* ,@l))
)
```

But I think this doesn't stop multiplicating untill it checks all the variables.

Comment: `&rest` arguments are not of infinite lengths. They can be as short as the value of the variable `call-arguments-limit`, which can be as low as 50. Thus in portable code you can't assume that the function allows more than 50 numbers as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

An `unless` form evaluates to `nil` when the predicate doesn't hit so:

```
(macroexpand-1 '(smart-multiplication 1 2 0))    
; ==> nil
```

Perhaps you should use `ìf` since you rather want it to become zero?

```
(defmacro smart-multiplication (&rest l)
  (if (member 0 l)
      0
      `(* ,@l)))

(macroexpand-1 '(smart-multiplication 1 2 3 0)) 
; ==> 0
(macroexpand-1 '(smart-multiplication 1 2 3)) 
; ==> (* 1 2 3)
```

Note that it only works for literal zeroes and since macros only knows about variables as symbols and never anything about their values it won't work when you have a zero variable:

```
(defparameter *zero* 0)
(macroexpand-1 '(smart-multiplication 1 2 3 *zero*)) 
; ==> (* 1 2 3 *zero*)
```

Basically you cannot think about macros as a program computation since it only abstracts code. Thus making syntax that is rewritten into something that Common Lisp supports. eg. `unless` is a macro:

```
(macroexpand-1 '(unless some-predicate
                  result-1
                  result-2))
; ==> (if (not some-predicate) (progn result-1 result-2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check at runtime the value for being zero.

```
(defmacro smart-multiplication (&rest list)
  (if (null list)
      1
    (let ((n0sym (gensym "mult")))
      `(let ((,n0sym ,(first list)))
         (if (zerop ,n0sym)
              0
            (* ,n0sym (smart-multiplication ,@(rest list))))))))

CL-USER 42 > (smart-multiplication (print 1) (print 2) (print 3))

1 
2 
3 
6

CL-USER 43 > (smart-multiplication (print 1) (print 0) (print 3))

1 
0 
0
```

The generated code, fully expanded by using the Lispworks *code walker*:

```
CL-USER 46 > (pprint (walker:walk-form
                      '(smart-multiplication (print 1)
                                             (print 0)
                                             (print 3))))

(LET ((#:|mult973| (PRINT 1)))
  (IF (ZEROP #:|mult973|)
      0
    (* #:|mult973|
       (LET ((#:|mult974| (PRINT 0)))
         (IF (ZEROP #:|mult974|)
             0
           (* #:|mult974|
              (LET ((#:|mult975| (PRINT 3)))
                (IF (ZEROP #:|mult975|) 0 (* #:|mult975| 1)))))))))
```

**Problems**

Now that code still does not look really good.
Improvements are left as an exercise:

- a return from a block could be used to return 0, without executing the open `*` function calls.
- even better: don't use nested multiplication calls...

Hint for a simple solution: the generated code could be similar to this one:

```
(prog ((result 1)
       value)

  (setf value (print 1))
  (when (zerop value)
    (return 0))
  (setf result (* result value))

  (setf value (print 0))
  (when (zerop value)
    (return 0))
  (setf result (* result value))

  (setf value (print 3))
  (when (zerop value)
    (return 0))
  (setf result (* result value))

  (return result))
```